# Why am I getting connection refused exception for this Python script?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I was writing a Python script to grab lyrics of a song from azlyrics using the request module. This is the script I wrote:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php"
payload = {'q' : 'shape of you'}
r = requests.get(url, params = payload)
soup = bs(r.text,"html.parser")
try:
    link = soup.find('a', {'href':re.compile('http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/edsheeran/shapeofyou.html')})['href']
    link = link.replace('http', 'https')
    print(link)
    raw_data = requests.get(link)
except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
```

but I got an exception stating :

```
Max retries exceeded with url: /lyrics/edsheeran/shapeofyou.html (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbda00b37f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I read on the internet that I am probably trying to send too many requests. So I made the script sleep for some time :

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from time import sleep
url = "http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php"
payload = {'q' : 'shape of you'}
r = requests.get(url, params = payload)
soup = bs(r.text,"html.parser")
try:
    link = soup.find('a', {'href':re.compile('http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/edsheeran/shapeofyou.html')})['href']
    link = link.replace('http', 'https')
    sleep(60)
    print(link)
    raw_data = requests.get(link)
except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
```

but no luck!

So I tried the same with urllib.request

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from time import sleep
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php"
payload = {'q' : 'shape of you'}
r = requests.get(url, params = payload)
soup = bs(r.text,"html.parser")
try:
    link = soup.find('a', {'href':re.compile('http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/edsheeran/shapeofyou.html')})['href']
    link = link.replace('http', 'https')
    sleep(60)
    print(link)
    raw_data = urlopen(link).read()
except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
```

but then got different exception stating :

```
<urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Can anyone one tell me whats wrong with it and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it in your web browser; when you try to visit http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/edsheeran/shapeofyou.html it'll work fine, but when you try to visit https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/edsheeran/shapeofyou.html it won't work.

So remove your `link = link.replace('http', 'https')` line and try again.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I wish I could upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation now.

Comment: No problem. What do you mean by 'working with requests'? You can [mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) with your reputation :)

Comment: To get your code to run I had to make some edits, like change the library import from `from urllib.request import urlopen` to `from urllib import urlopen`?